# How to write the query statement in Apache IoTDB to both use `group by` and constant generating function in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is it possible to simultaneously use the constant time series generating functions and `group by` function at the same time in Apache IoTDB? I understand that `group by` and individual fields cannot be used at the same time in the query statment, but can the constant column generation function be used with `group by` at the same time? Currently I tried to write query statment like `select avg(cast(val, 'type'='double')) as val, const(val, 'value'='test', 'type'='text') as c from root.db1 group by ([2024-02-01T00:00:00,2024-02-20T00:00:00),1h)`, but there is an error message: `701: Raw data and aggregation hybrid query is not supported`. How can I use these two functions at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache IoTDB, you CAN use `const` function and `group by` function in one query statement. For your error, you can try to change your query statement to using `FIRST_VALUE` to solve the problem, for example `select avg(cast(val,'type'='DOUBLE'))as val,FIRST_VALUE(const(val, 'value'='test', 'type'='TEXT')) as c from root.db1 group by ([2024-02-01T00:00:00,2024-02-20T00:00:00),1h)`.